# Assign variable value to asynchronous method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

help me, I want to set variable value into asynchronous method (data is load from db), the problem is value will set to last record. here is my code :

```
var _resolve = {
    lazyLoad: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
        return $ocLazyLoad.load(angular.copy(angular.fromJson(menu.resolve)));
    }]
}
```

example data :

```
> -- one.js
> -- two.js
> -- three.js
```

from the code above, menu.resolve is object from database, menu resolve will return "three.js" in all rows. how to set variable value into each row?

Thank! :)

Comment: Sounds like you're going to need to parse the JSON response and manually update the DOM appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typical of javascript nature what you need to do is use an iffy closure to solve this issue I will give u an example

```
for(var i=0;i<=2;i++;)
{
             (function(myVar) { // this will hold a value of i
                   $("#someDom").append(myVar)//whatever ur logic should be here
             })(i);
}
```

Comment: Creating function inside a loop is a **terrible practice**, causes even more damage to those new to javascript who might not even understand the consequences.

Comment: thank! my prob is solved now, here is my changed code :


state = {
         url: menu.url,
         title: menu.title,
         icon: menu.icon,
               
         templateUrl: menu.template_url,
         controller: menu.controller,
         resolve : ResolverFunc(menu)
       }

i placed function in outside of looping.